# HTML 3 rows (divs) in a container with 33.333333% of height, responsive to containers height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am looking for a way to arrange 3 divs which will occupy in total the 100% of the containers height.

Example markup

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item-3"></div>
</div>
```

So that means for example that if the container is 300px in height, then each item should be 100px in height or should have 33.33333% height of the parent.

I have some ideas, mostly with js and doing all the maths there but it would be great if there is a pure css solution.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%
}

.container [class^=item-]{
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33333%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for percent width/height from parent. You can always do it with height = 33% in the child divs.